# Rails activestorage does not create migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, image-upload, ruby-on-rails-6

I make an image-upload for a user profile using the activestorage gem built into rails, but it is not working, the intriguing part is that there are no errors, the migration just does not get created.

What is wrong here, any ideas on how I can fix this?

rails version - 6.0

I added `require 'active_storage/engine'` to the `config/application.rb` file already
And then ran `rails active_storage:install`

What is even more intriguing is that I get the same output without adding the `require active_storage/engine` to application.rb. And there are no errors

output

````
** Invoke active_storage:install (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute active_storage:install
** Invoke active_storage:install:migrations (first_time)
** Execute active_storage:install:migrations
** Invoke railties:install:migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute railties:install:migrations```

I expect the migration file to be created after this but it is not.
````

Comment: @MarkMerritt yes I did, but I get the same output, regardless. Also, I saw on the active storage Github page that it is okay to add it if the task cannot be found, I am not sure what that means since I do not get error output

Comment: No migration is created, so I assume there is an error somewhere but nothing shows up on the terminal

Comment: Still the same thing, I update my question to reflect that

Comment: Maybe the migrations are already added, can you see and confirm `schema.rb` file?